# Print all configurations python list

Tags: python

I have 10 variables x1 to x10 and size of number of possible values for each variable ranges from 1 to 256.

```
x1 = [1,10,20,23,12]
x2 = ['string0','string1','string3']
```

I need to generate all possible configurations

```
1, string0,..... <till x10 value>
1, string1
1, string3
......
12, string0
12, string1
12, string3
```

I am currently nested for to loop over all x1 to x10 like

```
for i in x1:
      for j in x2:
          ......
          print(i,j,k,.....)
```

The output doesnt print beyond three or four for loops. Is there any better way to print all possible configurations into a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `product` method from `itertools` module:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> x1 = [1,10,20,23,12]
>>> x2 = ['string0','string1','string3']
>>> list(it.product(x1, x2))

[(1, 'string0'),
 (1, 'string1'),
 (1, 'string3'),
 (10, 'string0'),
 (10, 'string1'),
 (10, 'string3'),
 (20, 'string0'),
 (20, 'string1'),
 (20, 'string3'),
 (23, 'string0'),
 (23, 'string1'),
 (23, 'string3'),
 (12, 'string0'),
 (12, 'string1'),
 (12, 'string3')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a list comprehension, iterating over both the lists `x1` and `x2` is enough

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> res = [(a,b) for a in x1 for b in x2]
>>> pprint(res)
[(1, 'string0'),
 (1, 'string1'),
 (1, 'string3'),
 (10, 'string0'),
 (10, 'string1'),
 (10, 'string3'),
 (20, 'string0'),
 (20, 'string1'),
 (20, 'string3'),
 (23, 'string0'),
 (23, 'string1'),
 (23, 'string3'),
 (12, 'string0'),
 (12, 'string1'),
 (12, 'string3')]
```

Comment: This by itself doesn't extend nicely to a collection of 10 lists. The question gives two lists as an example, but the actual problem contains `x1` through `x10`.